# Can't start CPAN shell

Tags: perl

When attempting to run CPAN I get:

> Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at /usr/share/perl/5.12/CPAN.pm line 508.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had such a problem and suspected something to do with proxy configuration that did not work for some of the accesses from CPAN... Have not looked deeper, but try checking this [ActiveState community thread](http://community.activestate.com/forum-topic/undefined-value-symbol-reference-net-ftp-dataconn-pm-line-55) to see if it helps you. 
Will pop in again to see if there are answers useful to both of us `:-)`